# Why do we need inner classes?

Tags: apex, inner-class

Can anyone give me an example when an inner class is used. I started with wrapper class and found inner class is used in that but as i am all new to this i was thinking if anyone can give me an simpler example for inner class use so I understand why its used and why it helps in situations .

Thanks

Comment: Class can describe objects. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming. And sometimes, if classes are really small, it make zero sense to create a separate file for it (f.e wrapper classes/ deserialization types)

Comment: @kurunve I'd disagree with the Wrapper Class example. If you write a lot of code that requires the use of, say, a `ContactWrapper`. It'd eventually make more sense to put that into it's own class rather constantly "rewriting the wheel".

Comment: @DanJones  your opinion makes some sense. I pointed that in "if classes are really small".